Change password for private key stored in Windows registry
During the process of creating a certificate request via certmgr.msc, a private key with a password was created.
Now, after i recieved certificate, i want to change private key password.
Is there any ways to do it?

No, you would have to recreate the certificate

Couldn't openssl be used to do so after exporting the key to a file?
